# TCP handshake for HTTP Response?

Tags: sockets, http, networking, tcp

Since HTTP is an application layer protocol using TCP, if I request to download a big file via HTTP here is what happens:

My HTTP request is going to be fragmented into TCP packets, and TCP is going to do a 3-way handshake and send my request packets to server. My question is the response from server ( the file) going to pass through old TCP connection, or server initiates another Transport layer connection with my browser and another 3-way handshake in order to send me the file?

Comment: Unlike protocols like `ftp` the `http` and `https` protocols do _not_ open additional sockets / connections for file transfer. Actually a file transfer is nothing special in those protocols at all, they work exactly like any other response a http server returns: headers, blank line, payload.

Comment: @arkascha so simple http response is going to happen along the request socket?? it means no additional handshakes for response??

Comment: Take a look yourself, this is not rocket science: start a network sniffer like `wireshark` and make a single file download request to a http server. You capture the reply, in there you clearly see the headers at the top (file type, transfer encoding, size, et all) and then the payload, the file in this case. Actually the server would not have any means to open a second socket, since the network topology usually simply does not allow that due to `NAT` solutions getting used on the client side.

Comment: Also it might be a good practice for you to implement a simple file download inside an http server environment yourself: you create a simple php script that receives a request for a file, checks if the requested file exists, sends some basic headers first and then simply adds the files content as payload. You will find millions of examples for that alone here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file transfer will use the existing connection. that will however make the connection busy until the file is transferred.

So if the user clicks on a link while the file is downloaded the connection is then busy. The web browser will therefore have to open an additional connection to be able to request the clicked url.

In HTTP/1.1 existing connections will be used if idle (idle connections will be closed when a period of time have passed).

Comment: Not in HTTP/1.1, which reuses the same connection by default.

Comment: @jch: A download can take a couple of minutes. Do you mean that the web browser should wait until the download is finished instead of opening a new connection (when the user clicks on a link)? (that's why I wrote ***can*** instead of ***will***)

Comment: Agreed, but I still think your comment is misleading.  Perhaps you could make it clear that reusing connections is done?